# Can I use native-borne instead of native-born?

Tags: word-choice

I know people generally use the expression, 'native-born' to indicate someone who was born in her/his native country.

But, is it OK to use an expression like "native-borne students" if I want to emphasize the context of the native country which has attempted to change and carry those students somewhere in which the country could easily manage and control them?

Is it totally wrong to use 'native-borne', instead of 'native-born'?

Thank you.

Comment: Example of current usage - [nativeborne](https://www.nativeborne.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. I'm afraid you will have to use more words than the hyphenated *native-borne* to describe the phenomenon you've described.

*Born* and *borne* are simply not the same, denotatively. *Born* means to come into being. A native-born person came into being in a given country. *Borne* [means](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/borne) carried, transported, or transmitted, literally. Here are some sample sentences with borne and its cognates:

- James had *borne* the weight of guilt for many years.
- The supplies for the expedition were *borne* on the backs of mules.
- Hester Prynne is the protagonist of Nathaniel Hawthorne's novel *The Scarlet Letter*, and she *bore* the letter A on her chest as punishment for having committed the crime of adultery.
- You will have to *bear* the burden of knowing you could have helped Sally, but chose not to.

As for the use of *native-borne* to describe citizens being "carried" to a place where they are more easily managed and controlled, you could describe that action by saying, for example,

> The native-born citizens of Bithynia [a made-up name for a country] were borne by transport trucks to an internment camp where they would be under the strict supervision of the power elite.

Answer (score 2):

Born means 'existing as a result of birth', and 'borne' means 'carried or transported by the thing specified'. 'Native-borne' is not something a native English speaker would say or write.

Comment: It might be written if it is to mean "borne by natives". I can envisage a nineteenth-century novel set in Africa, for example [although that example wouldn't acceptable today, I think].